# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PL/SQL Block return type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

As part of a test I want to run a PL/SQL block using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` but when I try to fetch the result with `INTO` it always returns the same error regardless the content of the PL/SQL block I want to run.

```
DECLARE
    l_output    VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN COMMIT; END;' INTO l_output;
END;
/
```

And the error is

```
ORA-01007: variable not in select list
```

I know this error has to with `l_output` not being the same type as the returning type by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, but I don't know the type. I already tried to change `l_output` to `CLOB`, `BLOB`, `NUMBER` and nothing changes. Any idea?

OK, this is another example, same result.

```
DECLARE
    l_output    VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(''TEST''); END;' INTO l_output;
END;
/
```

Comment: The anonymous block you are calling does not have any bind variables to return... what are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: If you're merely checking if the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE was successful, try wrapping it in a BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END block.

Comment: As to your edit, I don't believe such functionality exists in Oracle plsql.  Capturing text output to screen doesn't exist because it depends on how the *client* renders the result.  For example, if `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST')` is executed in SQL*Plus while `SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF` is set, the output will be empty but Oracle has no way of knowing such.

Comment: A PL/SQL block has no return type.  Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do and why?  If you're trying to build a generic "run any command, return the result" system, there are ways to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle is complaining because your PL/SQL does not return anything for it to store in `l_output`.  What are you expecting the value of `l_output` to be?

One would use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`...`INTO` with something like this to return a value from a PL/SQL block.

```
DECLARE
    l_output    VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ''ABC'' FROM DUAL' INTO l_output;
    dbms_output.put_line('l_output = ' || l_output);
END;
/
```

#### UPDATE

If you want, you can do this:

```
DECLARE
    l_output    VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :1 := 5; END;' USING IN OUT l_output;
    dbms_output.put_line('l_output = ' || l_output);
END;
```

Comment: nop, I need the command to be a PL/SQL block, not a direct DDL instruction, I just added another example

Comment: Your second example does not return anything, either.  Text sent to `DBMS_OUTPUT` is not a "return value" as far as PL/SQL is concerned.  Rather, it is something your client may read and display after PL/SQL is finished executing altogether.  However I've updated my answer to show how you could return a value from PL/SQL, if you actually had one.

Comment: yeah, we think this will do the trick, also for a more complex problem we thought about inserting into a table and after the `EXECUTE` statement we can look for it